# Cannot access Issuer url from Azure AB B2C metadata : Error 404

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-ad-b2c

For implementing Azure AD B2C in Microsoft Dynamics portals, I followed [this series of article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c).

I created a new Azure AB B2C, linked it to my Azure subscription (a free one if that helps), created an Azure app, a signup or signin policy.

Then I clicked on the metadata url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/MyJavistaB2CPocTest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration), selected the Issuer url and paste it on a browser.

It gets a 404 error.

I asked some help and the guy that helps me had an issuer url with the tenant included, something like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi/v2.0/

Whereas mine has a guid instead (maybe it's a clue but cannot tell): https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/8701db3f-1609-4337-8e6d-b5a32d537c54/b2c_1_susi/v2.0/

What could be the cause of not being able to reach the issuer url (which makes then my Dynamics Portal unable to contact Azure AD B2C)?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, you can use the guid id of your tenant or the name.onmicrosoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `issuer` value isn't an endpoint URL.

Rather, applications must match the `iss` claim in the ID and access tokens, which are issued by Azure AD B2C, with the `issuer` value, to ensure these tokens are valid.

In Dynamics 365, you should configure `Authentication/OpenIdConnect/[Federation-Name]/Authority` (described as "Policy-Signin-URL" in the [Azure AD B2C provider settings for portals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c) article) with the following URL, from which Dynamics 365 will discover the Azure AD B2C endpoints:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/MyJavistaB2CPocTest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/v2.0

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I was sure I have tested it before but I may have done something wrong too.